# How can I concatenate vector and cell in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have matrix `F` of dimension 5 X 3. For example:

```
 F= [1 12 13; 
    2 23 24; 
    3 34 35; 
    4 45 46;
    5 56 57]
```

and I have a label cell of size 1X1  with entry 'v' i.e.

```
>> label

     label = 

       'v'
```

and size of F is given by :

```
>> [m n]=size(F)

     m=

      5

    n =

      3
```

I want my output to look like:

```
>> F

    F =

         1    12    13   v
         2    23    24   v
         3    34    35   v
         4    45    46   v
         5    56    57   v
```

How can I concatenate the cell with the matrix to get this output?

Comment: Is label really a cell or just a char?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: from the displayed output, it's quite clearly a cell. If it was a `char`, there wouldn't be any apostrophes around `v`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an array that contains both numeric and non-numeric data, you need to put everything into a cell array (replace `label` by `{label}` in case it isn't a cell array):

```
Fcell = [ num2cell(F), repmat(label,size(F,1),1)]
```

You can then access individual numbers/letters using the curly brackets:

```
Fcell{2,2}

ans =
   23
```

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: If `label` wasn't a cell, then `{label}` will fix that. However, the OP states and the `disp` output confirms that it is actually a cell array.

Comment: @Dennis: I rolled back your edit, since I don't think it's necessary. I have added a note to clarify, though

Comment: @ Jonas: Thanks it worked, even though the output is a cell and not same as of displayed output but I can work further with this. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonas described, converting it to cells is the way to go when you want to access the data for further use.
However, if you are solely interested in seeing the data on the screen and don't like the brackets this is also an option:

```
Fcell = [num2str(F) repmat([' ' label{1}],size(F,1),1)]
```

If your label is actually a char it should work like this:

```
Fcell = [num2str(F) repmat([' ' label],size(F,1),1)]
```

Comment: Label is a cell and I run the code :  Fcell = [num2str(F) repmat([' ' {label}],size(F,1),1)]; but is is giving me error:Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: @Dev I have updated my post, now the brackets should be used correctly.

Comment: Thanks!!, it worked and gives me same output as displayed in my question but output is of class char. and if I access Fcell(2,2) its not 23.  Jonas way of creating a cell produces Fcell{2,2}=23.

Comment: @Dev As mentioned this is for printing purposes only, if you want to use the data do what Jonas recommended.